# Three number lotttery guessing game C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, random

I have been stuck on this one problem for the last few days and this is my last resort. Any input is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

The requirements are to create a program that generates three random numbers and allows the user to guess three numbers, giving rewards for different matches. Currently, the program only recognizes one match and will not display if there is more than one number matching.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>   // Needed for actual random number
#include <cstdlib>  

using namespace std;


int main()
{   
    int guess1, guess2, guess3;
    int random1, random2, random3;
    int exactCount = 0;
    int inexactCount = 0;

    /// initialize random seed /// 
    srand(time(NULL));  

    /// Generate three random numbers /// 
    random1 = rand() % 9 + 1;
    random2 = rand() % 9 + 1;
    random3 = rand() % 9 + 1;

    /// Accept three guesses ///
    cout << "Guess a number between 1 and 9: ";
    cin >> guess1;
    cout << "Guess another number between 1 and 9: ";
    cin >> guess2;
    cout << "Guess another number between 1 and 9: ";
    cin >> guess3;

    /// Test random numbers ///
    cout << "Number 1: " << random1 << endl << "Number 2: " << random2 << endl << "Number 3: " << random3 << endl;

    system("PAUSE");

    /// Count number of exact and inexact matches /// 
    if (guess1 == random1){
        exactCount++;
    }
    else if (guess1 == random2 || guess1 == random3){
        inexactCount;
    }
    if (guess2 == random2)
    {
        exactCount++;
    }
    else if (guess2 == random1 || guess2 == random3){
        inexactCount;
    }
    if (guess3 == random3){
        exactCount++;
    }
    else if(guess3 == random1 || guess3 == random2){
        inexactCount++;
    }

    int matches = exactCount + inexactCount;

    /// Check counts and display winnings /// 
    if (exactCount == 3){
        cout << "JACKPOT!!! Three matching in a row! You win $100!!!";
    }
    else
    {
        if (matches == 0) cout << "No matches at all, you lose!" << endl;
        else if (matches == 3) cout << "Three matching not in order! You win $50!" << endl;
        else if (matches == 2) cout << "Two matching numbers! You win $20!" << endl;
        else if (matches == 1) cout << "One matching number! You win $10!" << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by inexactCount; at one of the else if ( ... ) conditions? You need to increment it ?

Comment: in other words: `inexactCount;` does nothing; do `inexactCount++;`.

Comment: I guess you didn't learn about `for` loops and `arrays`?  This code could be cut in half if you used those concepts.

Comment: I just posted and answer in which I think I took care of this :)

Comment: @svasa - Thats it! I cant believe I didnt increment the  inexact count! If they were guessed correctly but not in the exact order than inexact count is incremented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work fine! I added in an `unordered_set` in the case you wanted to increase the cardinality of the random numbers :)

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
#include <unordered_set>
using std::unordered_set;
#include <cstdlib>
#include <time.h>
#include <array>
using std::array;

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    unordered_set<int> set_of_random_values;

    // insert 3 random values into the set of integers
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        set_of_random_values.insert(rand() % 9 + 1);
    }

    // now ask the user for input
    array<int, 3> guesses;
    for (auto& guess : guesses) {
        cout << "Enter a guess ";
        cin >> guess;
    }

    // print the 3 values
    cout << "The three values were : ";
    for (auto integer : set_of_random_values) {
        cout << integer << ' ';
    } cout << endl;

    int matches = 0;
    for (auto integer : guesses) {
        if (set_of_random_values.find(integer) != set_of_random_values.end()) {
            ++matches;
        }
    }

    if (matches == 0) cout << "No matches at all, you lose!" << endl;
    else if (matches == 3) cout << "Three matching not in order! You win $50!" << endl;
    else if (matches == 2) cout << "Two matching numbers! You win $20!" << endl;
    else if (matches == 1) cout << "One matching number! You win $10!" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And as pointed out by @PaulMackinzie I just wanted to say that you should use loops like I have in my above example and try to not duplicate code as well!

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response! My instructor actually requested that we did NOT use loops to do this for some reason. I want to have the most concise code possible and I'm not sure why he would favor us learning redundant code. Thank you for showing me a more efficient way of accomplishing this

Comment: Even the `matches` text at the end can be placed in an array, thus making the output a 1-liner.